# Android Service which keeps track of my current location and/or speed

Tags: android, performance, service, gps, location

I want to write a **Service** which keeps track of my current location (and a different Service for my speed).
I've seen some code examples, but all them are for Activities and not for Services.
I want the Service to keep track until I stop it.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a SERVICE which keeps track of my current location (and a different Service for my speed).

You can do both tasks with one service. You do not need two services.

> How do i do it?

Call `requestLocationUpdates()` on a `LocationManager` in `onCreate()` of your `Service`. Call `removeUpdates()` in `onDestroy()` of your `Service`. Collect the location and speed data in `onLocationChanged()` of the `LocationListener` that you supplied to `requestLocationUpdates()`. Make sure that the user has complete control over when `startService()` and `stopService()` are called. Also, request the appropriate permission (e.g., `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`).

Comment: Do i need a particular BIND ? How do i know the service wont stop by itself if i dont call stopService ?

Comment: @ErelHansav: *You* are the one who decided that you want to use services. Hence, *you* are the one who needs to make sure that you stop those services. If you wish to use `bindService()`, you are welcome to do so.